# Apache Pig : Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING

Tags: apache-pig

I am using Apache Pig. I am trying to load a comma separated file as a Pig table. It does not throw any error while loading the file.
But when I try to print that table using "dump" command, it gives error.

File I loaded

```
Error,fdgdf
Error,dfgdf
Error,dfgdf
Info,dfgdf
Info,dfgdf
Info,dfgdf
Info,dfgdf
Info,dfgdf
Info,dfgdf
Debug,dfgdf
Debug,dfgdf
Debug,dfgdf
Debug,dfgdf
Debug,dfgdf
Debug,dfgdf
```

Command to load

```
logFile1 = LOAD  'PigTestFile' using PigStorage();
```

Command to print table

```
dump logFile1
```

Error I get

```
led Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_1454617624671_0152  logFile1        MAP_ONLY        Message: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: hdfs:
//ip-172-31-53-48.ec2.internal:8020/user/e1681fe26eed362777aabca1682510/PigTestFile
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:279)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:301)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:318)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:196)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.submit(PigJobControl.java:128)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop23.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:194)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:276)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://ip-172-31-53-48.ec2.internal:8020/user/e1681fe26eed362777aabca1682510/PigTestFile
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:265)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigTextInputFormat.listStatus(PigTextInputFormat.java:36)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:387)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:265)
        ... 18 more
        hdfs://ip-172-31-53-48.ec2.internal:8020/tmp/temp1258481141/tmp-1928081547,
:
:
2016-02-07 06:31:20,100 [main] INFO      org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
2016-02-07 06:31:20,107 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias logFile1. Backend error :     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING
```

**[EDIT]** 
When I closely read the log I found that it is not able to find the file which was used to load the table. It is expecting it to be in HDFS. Where as my file was on local box. 
I then moved the file into HDFS and then ran same commands. It worked well.

**But then why did it not give error while executing "Load" command itself ??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map/ Reduce jobs for a script will get triggered only when STORE/ DUMP is encountered.

In this case, Map phase for LOAD command will start only when STORE/ DUMP is encountered in script.

Default execution mode is map reduce. If the file is in local path you have use local mode for execution.

```
pig -x local {pigfilename.pig}
```

**Refer :** https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/start.html#execution-modes

**Extract from above link :**

> Pig has two execution modes or exectypes:
>
> Local Mode - To run Pig in local mode, you need access to a single
>   machine; all files are installed and run using your local host and
>   file system. Specify local mode using the -x flag (pig -x local).
>   Mapreduce Mode - To run Pig in mapreduce mode, you need access to a
>   Hadoop cluster and HDFS installation. Mapreduce mode is the default
>   mode; you can, but don't need to, specify it using the -x flag (pig OR
>   pig -x mapreduce).

Comment: So if it was running in MR mode by default, why did it now complain for "Load" command itself ?

Comment: Map/ Reduce jobs for a script will get triggered only when STORE/ DUMP is encountered. Map phase for LOAD command will start only when STORE/ DUMP is encountered in script.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and put this as first one, so one can quickly get this.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by Murali in his answer (which I have accepted) Map/ Reduce jobs for a script will get triggered only when STORE/ DUMP is encountered.

Here is more explanation about it from [Apache Pig documentation](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref1.html)

---

In general, Pig processes Pig Latin statements as follows:

First, Pig validates the syntax and semantics of all statements.
Next, if Pig encounters a DUMP or STORE, Pig will execute the statements.
In this example Pig will validate, but not execute, the LOAD and FOREACH statements.

```
A = LOAD 'student' USING PigStorage() AS (name:chararray, age:int, gpa:float);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE name;
```

In this example, Pig will validate and then execute the LOAD, FOREACH, and DUMP statements.

```
A = LOAD 'student' USING PigStorage() AS (name:chararray, age:int, gpa:float);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE name;
DUMP B;

(John)
(Mary)
(Bill)
(Joe)
```

---